# How to map multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array of arrays that I need to consolidate into another array.

I have tried mapping over it, matching object_id, and gathering all account_ids for said object_id, but all my attempts are not even close as I am trying to learn PHP

This is the original array

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [rank] => 0
        [id] => 6
        [object_id] => 3
        [account_id] => 13
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [rank] => 1
        [id] => 7
        [object_id] => 3
        [account_id] => 565
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [rank] => 2
        [id] => 1823
        [object_id] => 825
        [account_id] => 563
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [rank] => 3
        [id] => 1824
        [object_id] => 825
        [account_id] => 564
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [rank] => 4
        [id] => 1825
        [object_id] => 825
        [account_id] => 565
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [rank] => 5
        [id] => 7187
        [object_id] => 3113
        [account_id] => 564
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [rank] => 6
        [id] => 7188
        [object_id] => 3113
        [account_id] => 565
    )
```

This is the desired result

```
 [3] => [13, 565],
 [825] => [563, 564, 565],
 [3113] => [564, 565],
```

Comment: Please, post what you have already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new `array` by using `object_id` index.

**Example:**

```
<?
$array = array(
  array('rank'=>0,'id'=>6,'object_id'=>3,'account_id'=>13),
  array('rank'=>1,'id'=>7,'object_id'=>3,'account_id'=>565),
  array('rank'=>2,'id'=>1823,'object_id'=>825,'account_id'=>563),
  array('rank'=>3,'id'=>1824,'object_id'=>825,'account_id'=>564),
  array('rank'=>4,'id'=>1825,'object_id'=>825,'account_id'=>565),
  array('rank'=>5,'id'=>7187,'object_id'=>3113,'account_id'=>564),
  array('rank'=>6,'id'=>7188,'object_id'=>3113,'account_id'=>565),
);

$newArray = array(); // initiliaze array
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $newArray[$value['object_id']][] = $value['account_id']; // save it in group
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray); // result
?>
```

[Running Example](https://paiza.io/projects/xT9rHC-ne5XAzSGTU00jXQ)

Comment: Thank you! Feel like an idiot.  I was actually really close in my attempts I was just clobbering my new array every time. Thanks! Learned a little something

Comment: @ss_matches: glad to help u

Comment: @ss_matches  FYI, if you had provided your attempted code in your question, that's a simple mistake that we easily could have pointed out.